# Add percent label by group by response to barplot in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, bar-chart, percentage

I'm trying to make a bar graph that shows the percentage of people who agree, disagree, and feel neutral about a topic by job type. On this graph, I want to do 2 things that I cannot figure out:

1. I want to include the percentages of each person within each job group that agrees, disagrees, and feels neutral. While I have found out how to add percents to the graph, the percent that shows in the label is the percent out of the TOTAL sample, not just the total by that specific job group. For instance, if my TOTAL sample has 1000 people but Job 1 only has 100 people, then if 10 people disagree, I want the label to say 10% (10/100); however, it currently says 1% (10 / 1000).
2. I want to add the sample n by job group to appear on the x axis under the title. For instance, under Job 1, I want it to say n = 100.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
 #colors
 RYG_Cols <- c("red", "yellow", "green3")

 #graph
dataset1 %>%
filter(!is.na(question1)) %>%
filter(jobgroup == "Job 1" | jobgroup == "Job 2" | jobgroup == "Job 3") %>%
ggplot(aes(x = jobgroup, fill = question1)) +
geom_bar(position = "fill")  +
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(), limits=c(0,1)) +
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12)) +
guides(fill=FALSE) +
ggtitle("Working Title") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "grey")) +
scale_fill_manual(values = RYG_Cols) + 
geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(round((..count..)/sum(..count..),2)), 
            y= ((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="count", position = 
position_fill(vjust=.5))
```

[Picture of Plot with above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHsvF.png)

EDIT: I was also asked to provide some sample data:

```
ID  jobgroup question1
1   Job 2   Agree
2   Job 2   Agree
3   Job 3   Agree
4   Job 3   Agree
5   Job 1   Agree
6   Job 3   Neutral
7   Job 2   Agree
8   Job 1   Agree
9   Job 3   Agree
10  Job 3   Agree
11  Job 1   Agree
12  Job 3   Agree
13  Job 1   Agree
14  Job 2   Agree
15  Job 2   Agree
16  Job 3   Agree
17  Job 3   Agree
18  Job 3   Agree
19  Job 2   Agree
20  Job 3   Agree
21  Job 3   Neutral
22  Job 1   Agree
23  Job 2   Agree
24  Job 3   Agree
25  Job 3   Disagree
26  Job 1   Agree
27  Job 1   Agree
28  Job 2   Agree
29  Job 3   Agree
30  Job 3   Agree
31  Job 3   Agree
32  Job 3   Agree
33  Job 1   Agree
34  Job 3   Agree
35  Job 3   Agree
36  Job 1   Agree
37  Job 3   Agree
38  Job 3   Agree
39  Job 3   Agree
40  Job 3   Agree
41  Job 3   Agree
42  Job 3   Agree
43  Job 3   Neutral
44  Job 2   Agree
45  Job 1   Agree
46  Job 3   Neutral
47  Job 3   Agree
48  Job 3   Disagree
49  Job 2   Agree
50  Job 3   Agree
51  Job 3   Neutral
52  Job 2   Neutral
53  Job 3   Neutral
54  Job 2   Agree
55  Job 1   Agree
56  Job 1   Agree
57  Job 1   Agree
58  Job 1   Agree
59  Job 3   Agree
60  Job 3   Agree
61  Job 3   Agree
62  Job 3   Agree
63  Job 2   Agree
64  Job 3   Agree
65  Job 3   Agree
66  Job 2   Agree
67  Job 2   Agree
68  Job 3   Agree
69  Job 3   Agree
70  Job 3   Agree
71  Job 3   Agree
72  Job 3   Agree
73  Job 3   Agree
74  Job 3   Agree
75  Job 2   Agree
76  Job 1   Agree
77  Job 1   Agree
78  Job 2   Neutral
79  Job 3   Agree
80  Job 2   Agree
81  Job 2   Agree
82  Job 3   Agree
83  Job 3   Agree
84  Job 3   Agree
85  Job 2   Agree
86  Job 3   Agree
87  Job 2   Agree
88  Job 3   Agree
89  Job 3   Neutral
90  Job 3   Agree
91  Job 3   Agree
92  Job 2   Agree
93  Job 3   Disagree
94  Job 3   Agree
95  Job 3   Agree
96  Job 3   Agree
97  Job 3   Agree
98  Job 3   Agree
99  Job 3   Agree
100 Job 3   Agree
101 Job 2   Agree
102 Job 3   Agree
103 Job 2   Agree
104 Job 2   Neutral
105 Job 3   Agree
106 Job 3   Disagree
107 Job 2   Agree
108 Job 3   Agree
109 Job 2   Agree
110 Job 3   Agree
111 Job 3   Agree
112 Job 2   Agree
113 Job 3   Neutral
114 Job 1   Agree
115 Job 1   Agree
116 Job 3   Agree
117 Job 2   Agree
118 Job 3   Agree
119 Job 3   Agree
120 Job 3   Agree
121 Job 3   Neutral
122 Job 3   Neutral
123 Job 3   Agree
124 Job 2   Agree
125 Job 3   Agree
126 Job 3   Agree
127 Job 1   Agree
128 Job 2   Neutral
129 Job 3   Neutral
130 Job 3   Disagree
131 Job 1   Agree
132 Job 2   Agree
133 Job 3   Agree
134 Job 3   Agree
135 Job 2   Agree
136 Job 3   Agree
137 Job 3   Agree
138 Job 3   Agree
139 Job 2   Agree
140 Job 2   Agree
141 Job 3   Agree
142 Job 3   Agree
143 Job 1   Agree
144 Job 2   Agree
145 Job 2   Agree
146 Job 3   Neutral
147 Job 2   Agree
148 Job 2   Agree
149 Job 1   Agree
150 Job 3   Agree
151 Job 3   Agree
152 Job 2   Agree
153 Job 3   Agree
154 Job 3   Agree
155 Job 1   Agree
156 Job 3   Agree
157 Job 3   Agree
158 Job 2   Agree
159 Job 3   Agree
160 Job 1   Agree
161 Job 1   Agree
162 Job 3   Agree
163 Job 3   Agree
164 Job 3   Agree
165 Job 3   Agree
166 Job 3   Agree
167 Job 3   Agree
168 Job 1   Agree
169 Job 3   Agree
170 Job 3   Agree
171 Job 1   Agree
172 Job 3   Agree
173 Job 3   Agree
174 Job 2   Agree
175 Job 2   Agree
176 Job 2   Agree
177 Job 3   Agree
178 Job 1   Agree
179 Job 2   Agree
180 Job 3   Agree
181 Job 3   Agree
182 Job 3   Agree
183 Job 1   Agree
184 Job 3   Agree
185 Job 3   Agree
186 Job 3   Agree
187 Job 1   Agree
188 Job 2   Agree
189 Job 1   Agree
190 Job 3   Agree
191 Job 3   Agree
192 Job 3   Agree
193 Job 3   Agree
194 Job 3   Agree
195 Job 3   Agree
196 Job 3   Agree
197 Job 3   Agree
198 Job 3   Agree
199 Job 2   Agree
200 Job 3   Agree
201 Job 1   Agree
202 Job 3   Agree
203 Job 3   Agree
204 Job 1   Agree
205 Job 3   Agree
206 Job 3   Agree
207 Job 3   Agree
208 Job 3   Agree
209 Job 1   Agree
210 Job 2   Agree
211 Job 2   Agree
212 Job 3   Agree
213 Job 3   Agree
214 Job 1   Agree
215 Job 3   Agree
216 Job 3   Agree
217 Job 3   Agree
218 Job 3   Agree
219 Job 1   Agree
220 Job 3   Agree
221 Job 1   Agree
222 Job 1   Agree
223 Job 3   Agree
224 Job 3   Agree
225 Job 3   Agree
226 Job 1   Neutral
227 Job 1   Agree
228 Job 1   Agree
229 Job 3   Agree
230 Job 3   Agree
231 Job 2   Agree
232 Job 2   Agree
233 Job 3   Agree
234 Job 3   Agree
235 Job 1   Agree
236 Job 2   Agree
237 Job 1   Agree
238 Job 3   Agree
239 Job 1   Agree
240 Job 3   Agree
241 Job 1   Agree
242 Job 3   Agree
243 Job 3   Agree
244 Job 3   Agree
245 Job 1   Agree
246 Job 3   Agree
247 Job 3   Agree
248 Job 3   Agree
249 Job 3   Agree
250 Job 1   Agree
251 Job 3   Agree
252 Job 1   Agree
253 Job 1   Agree
254 Job 3   Agree
255 Job 3   Agree
256 Job 3   Agree
257 Job 3   Neutral
258 Job 3   Agree
259 Job 1   Agree
260 Job 2   Agree
261 Job 3   Agree
262 Job 3   Agree
263 Job 1   Agree
264 Job 3   Agree
265 Job 1   Agree
266 Job 1   Agree
267 Job 1   Agree
268 Job 1   Agree
269 Job 2   Agree
270 Job 3   Agree
271 Job 3   Neutral
272 Job 3   Agree
273 Job 3   Agree
274 Job 3   Agree
275 Job 2   Agree
276 Job 2   Neutral
277 Job 3   Agree
278 Job 3   Agree
279 Job 1   Agree
280 Job 1   Agree
281 Job 3   Neutral
282 Job 1   Agree
283 Job 1   Agree
284 Job 3   Agree
285 Job 3   Agree
286 Job 2   Neutral
287 Job 1   Agree
288 Job 3   Agree
289 Job 2   Agree
290 Job 3   Agree
291 Job 3   Neutral
292 Job 2   Agree
293 Job 3   Agree
294 Job 3   Agree
295 Job 3   Agree
296 Job 1   Agree
297 Job 3   Neutral
298 Job 1   Agree
299 Job 2   Agree
300 Job 3   Agree
301 Job 3   Agree
302 Job 1   Agree
303 Job 3   Agree
304 Job 3   Agree
305 Job 2   Agree
306 Job 3   Agree
307 Job 1   Agree
308 Job 2   Agree
309 Job 2   Agree
310 Job 3   Agree
311 Job 1   Agree
312 Job 3   Agree
313 Job 3   Agree
314 Job 3   Agree
315 Job 3   Agree
316 Job 3   Agree
317 Job 1   Agree
318 Job 2   Agree
319 Job 3   Agree
320 Job 3   Agree
321 Job 3   Agree
322 Job 2   Agree
323 Job 3   Agree
324 Job 3   Agree
325 Job 3   Agree
326 Job 2   Neutral
327 Job 1   Agree
328 Job 2   Agree
329 Job 3   Agree
330 Job 3   Agree
331 Job 3   Agree
332 Job 3   Agree
333 Job 1   Agree
334 Job 2   Agree
335 Job 3   Agree
336 Job 3   Agree
337 Job 2   Agree
338 Job 1   Agree
339 Job 2   Neutral
340 Job 3   Agree
341 Job 3   Agree
342 Job 3   Agree
343 Job 3   Agree
344 Job 3   Agree
345 Job 3   Agree
346 Job 2   Agree
347 Job 1   Agree
348 Job 3   Agree
349 Job 3   Agree
350 Job 1   Agree
351 Job 3   Agree
352 Job 3   Disagree
353 Job 3   Agree
354 Job 3   Agree
355 Job 3   Neutral
356 Job 1   Agree
357 Job 3   Agree
358 Job 2   Agree
359 Job 3   Agree
360 Job 3   Agree
361 Job 3   Agree
362 Job 3   Agree
363 Job 3   Neutral
364 Job 3   Neutral
365 Job 1   Agree
366 Job 3   Agree
367 Job 3   Agree
368 Job 3   Agree
369 Job 3   Agree
370 Job 3   Agree
371 Job 1   Agree
372 Job 3   Agree
373 Job 3   Agree
374 Job 3   Agree
375 Job 3   Agree
376 Job 3   Agree
377 Job 1   Agree
378 Job 1   Agree
379 Job 3   Agree
380 Job 3   Agree
381 Job 2   Agree
382 Job 3   Agree
383 Job 3   Disagree
384 Job 3   Agree
385 Job 1   Agree
386 Job 1   Agree
387 Job 3   Agree
388 Job 2   Agree
389 Job 1   Agree
390 Job 2   Neutral
391 Job 3   Agree
392 Job 3   Neutral
393 Job 3   Agree
394 Job 1   Agree
395 Job 1   Agree
396 Job 3   Agree
397 Job 1   Agree
398 Job 3   Disagree
399 Job 3   Agree
400 Job 3   Disagree
401 Job 3   Agree
402 Job 2   Agree
403 Job 3   Agree
404 Job 1   Agree
405 Job 1   Agree
406 Job 1   Agree
407 Job 1   Agree
408 Job 1   Agree
409 Job 3   Agree
410 Job 1   Agree
411 Job 1   Disagree
412 Job 3   Neutral
413 Job 3   Agree
414 Job 3   Agree
415 Job 3   Agree
416 Job 1   Agree
417 Job 3   Agree
418 Job 3   Agree
419 Job 3   Agree
420 Job 2   Agree
421 Job 3   Agree
422 Job 3   Disagree
423 Job 3   Agree
424 Job 2   Agree
425 Job 1   Agree
426 Job 3   Agree
427 Job 1   Agree
428 Job 1   Agree
429 Job 1   Agree
430 Job 3   Agree
431 Job 1   Agree
432 Job 1   Agree
433 Job 1   Agree
434 Job 1   Agree
435 Job 3   Agree
436 Job 2   Agree
437 Job 3   Agree
438 Job 3   Agree
439 Job 3   Agree
440 Job 3   Agree
441 Job 2   Agree
442 Job 3   Agree
443 Job 1   Agree
444 Job 3   Agree
445 Job 2   Agree
446 Job 3   Agree
447 Job 3   Agree
448 Job 3   Agree
449 Job 2   Agree
450 Job 2   Agree
451 Job 3   Agree
452 Job 3   Neutral
453 Job 3   Agree
454 Job 1   Agree
455 Job 3   Agree
456 Job 3   Neutral
457 Job 2   Agree
458 Job 3   Agree
459 Job 3   Agree
460 Job 3   Agree
461 Job 3   Agree
462 Job 3   Agree
463 Job 3   Agree
464 Job 3   Agree
465 Job 2   Agree
466 Job 3   Agree
467 Job 3   Agree
468 Job 1   Agree
469 Job 3   Agree
470 Job 1   Agree
471 Job 2   Agree
472 Job 1   Agree
473 Job 1   Agree
474 Job 3   Agree
475 Job 3   Agree
476 Job 3   Agree
477 Job 1   Agree
478 Job 3   Neutral
479 Job 1   Agree
480 Job 3   Agree
481 Job 3   Disagree
482 Job 1   Agree
483 Job 1   Agree
484 Job 3   Agree
485 Job 3   Agree
486 Job 3   Neutral
487 Job 1   Agree
488 Job 1   Agree
489 Job 3   Neutral
490 Job 1   Agree
491 Job 1   Agree
492 Job 1   Agree
493 Job 3   Agree
494 Job 3   Agree
495 Job 3   Neutral
496 Job 3   Neutral
497 Job 3   Agree
498 Job 3   Agree
499 Job 3   Agree
500 Job 3   Agree
```

Comment: Please include an image of the desired output which may involve using an image software to show. And please fix indentation as piping and ggplot are spaced for readability on new lines.

Comment: can you provide a subset of your dataset?

Comment: Hi @shirin, I just uploaded a subset!

Comment: @J.Sabree just added my answer if that works please mark it up as the answer! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataset1$question1 <- factor(dataset1$question1, levels = c("Disagree","Agree","Neutral"))
ggplot(dataset1 %>% 
group_by(jobgroup) %>% 
count(question1) %>%    # Group by jobgroup, then count number in each question1
mutate(jobgroupCnt=paste(jobgroup," , n= ",sum(n), sep=""), #this variable gives the total count within each jobgroup
pct=n/sum(n)),     # Calculate percent within each jobgroup
aes(jobgroupCnt, pct, fill=question1,order=question1)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", pct*100),"%")),
position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),size=3)+
labs(title = "", y = "Percent", x = "Job Group")+ #add the title yourself 
theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
axis.text.x=element_text(hjust=0.5,vjust=0.5), #adjusted both vertically and horizontally on the center
panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.background = element_blank(),
axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect--thank you! I upvoted it, but it is not showing because I don't have enough reputation points. I really appreciate your help and time!!

Comment: @J.Sabree awesome! no problem this note is plenty :)